# Problems running ASP.NET application with IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have written a small ASP.NET application. It runs fine when running it with the small IIS installation that comes with Visual Studio 2005, but not when trying with IIS. I created the virtual directory in IIS where the application is located (done it though both IIS and VS 2005), but it does not work. In the beginning I thought it might be caused by the web.config file, but after a few tests, I think that the problem lies with IIS (not certain about it).

Some of the errors that I get are

> Unable to start debugging on the web server. The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error ocurred on a receiver. Click help for more information

Can anybody give me a suggestion of what to try next?

Answer (score 6):

Have you run [aspnet_regiis](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/187d0e2c-8e89-49ad-a89d-e26e4d76ee68.mspx?mfr=true)?

Here's an [overview site for different IIS versions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178477.aspx) setup and should help if there are other questions/issues

Comment: Good point...that's one of those things you do once and then forget about.

Answer (score 1):

Try reinstalling aspnet_regiis.exe.

If you are using .net frameworkype 4.0 and using 64 bit system,

Go to Run, Type cmd and Command Prompt will be up, then type

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```

If you are using 34 bit system,

Go to Run Type cmd and then type

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```

Answer (score 0):

The site won't load at all or you can't debug remotely?

Comment: It sounds like it won't load at all.

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts:

1. Make sure you've got debugging enabled in your web.config, if you're trying to debug.  Otherwise, build in 'Release' mode.
2. Make sure your project is set as an application, and is running as the correct version of .NET
3. More description of your setup and the error message would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the customErrors is set to off in the web.config. That should show the actual exception.

Make sure that your virtual directory in IIS is set to the correct version of the .NET framework.

Look at the properties in the virtual directory and see that the correct default documents are the ones that you are using in your dev project.

Also look at the url headers for the website in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

On some of our servers we have both versions of the .NET framework.  In IIS I typically have to set what version the virtual directory should be using.  This can cause problems running it on the server.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have installed and configured IIS server. To check whether IIS server is installed: Run->inetmgr press enter.
To know how to install and configure IIS server check the following Link:
http://chalaki.com/install-iis6-windows-xp-professional-sp3-setup-run-csharp-cgi/425/

To develop Website using Visual developer with IIS instead of "default ASP.NET Development Server", In the new website window under "Location" click on "Browse" to see the different Server options including IIS Server. User can select the server as IIS server instead of "File System", then the "Location" option will be "HTTP" instead of "File System".

In Visual developer 2008 under Properties->Start Option->Server->"Use local IIS server" option is not shown, Even though IIS server was installed and configured successfully. the only options shown are "use default server" and " Use custom server with base URL".

So in Visual developer 2008 to run on IIS server(If IIS server is installed), Need do the following:

New Website -> Under Locations Click on "Browse" -> Click on "Local IIS" and then select the "IIS Virtual Directory"(IIS vitual Directory which is directory created by the user while configuring IIS server) -> Open

While Running/debugging, the server which you selected while creating the website, the same server will used to open the website, that is while creating the website if you selected "IIS Server" then the website will be opened though IIS server.

One more thing is, while installing Visual developer 2008 and IIS server, If you installed IIS server after installing Visual studio then you need to do the following before creating new website:

Run ->cmd press enter (then enter the following Command)-> C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\Version# aspnet_regiis -i     press Enter then you get message after 3 seconds "ASP.net was installed successfully".
(*Version# will be v2.0.50727 in most cases)

Comment: Exact same answer posted for this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/478870/how-do-i-get-visual-web-developer-to-use-iis-and-not-asp-net-development-server/8345692#8345692